# TYPO3 7.6: 'divide' a variable in a fluid template

Tags: fluid-layout, typo3-7.6.x

I have a variable {index.originalObject.title} that contains two informations:

1) event name
2) Location

The two parts are always separated by " - "

Example: Großes Sommerfest - München

Is there a possibility in a fluid template to select the 'event name' first and than the 'location'?
I want to put the two parts in different columns in a table.

Comment: I guess there is no positive answer for this question. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using the Explode Viewhelper? I never used it before, but according to the doc entry it should do want you need.

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Iterator/ExplodeViewHelper.html

As a sidenote or question. Is there a specific reason why you don't separate the attributes in the database?

Happy Coding!